# How do I set the refresh rate used by KMS on the FOSS ati driver?

Tags: boot, xorg, video, ati, kms

With KMS enabled on Xubuntu 11.04, my virtual terminals are running at 60hz, the default for my monitor, while my X desktop is running at 75, the refresh rate I specified in my xorg.conf. How do I set the refresh rate/mode used by KMS so that it is something different from the default mode provided by my monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the resolution/refresh rate that the VT framebuffers will use on the kernel command line¹.

To do so, you want to add

```
video=<xres>x<yres>@<refresh>
```

to your kernel command line.  So, for example

```
video=1024x768@75
```

would give you a `1024x768` framebuffer at 75Hz.  The `@<refresh>` bit is optional.

You can edit your kernel command line on a one-time basis by hitting `e` from the grub menu, or to set it permanently you can edit `/etc/default/grub`, adding it to the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

like so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=1024x768@75"
```

After editing `/etc/default/grub` you'll need to run `sudo update-grub` to propagate the configuration to your boot settings.

Documentation/fb/modedb.txt has the full specification of what options you can pass in to `video=` - if you have unusual requirements (interlaced, reduced-blanking, etc) see this documentation.

¹: This is due in part to the fact that there's no good way to notify VT users of resolution changes.

Comment: Notes to future readers as nooby as me:

Add the video option to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT option, as such: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=1280x1024@75 quiet splash"

Be sure to run update-grub.